# Телеграм-бот не реагирует на команду

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Телеграм-бот по какой-то причине не реагирует на одну из команд.
В коде есть 2 хендлера, хватающих эту команду: первый её пропускает и выходит из функции (так и должно быть), а второй, вроде как, ловит, но позже ничего не происходит. Код функции не запускается.
При чём, хендлер для отлова "белеберды" не срабатывает, соответственно, команда всё-же отлавливается, но я не понимаю, почему ничего не происходит.

Код неисправного(?) хендлера (вместе с функцией регистрации):

```
async def mark_all_tasks(message: types.Message):
    current_todo = await get_chosen_list(message.from_user.id)
    tagged_tasks = await db_executor("""SELECT * FROM user%s WHERE is_done = false
                                     AND todo_name = %s;""", message.from_user.id, current_todo)
    if not tagged_tasks:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Упс, кажется, все задания уже выполненны.')
        return
    await db_executor("""UPDATE user%s SET is_done = true WHERE todo_name = %s;""", message.from_user.id, current_todo)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Все задания отмечены как выполненные!')
    await bot.send_animation(message.from_user.id,
                             'CgACAgIAAxkBAAIL4GLzepgSQEDZNuVMiFAQNfIVtineAALODwACn89pStVBA7CQ2fsTKQQ')
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Теперь ваш список выглядит так: ')
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, await build_todo(message.from_user.id))


def register_taskmarking_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(mark_task, state=GeneralFSM.marktask)
    dp.register_message_handler(mark_all_tasks, commands=['mark_all_tasks'])
```

Код хендлера, который отлавливает команду (работа кода спускается сразу к последнему else):

```
async def invoke_fsm(message: types.Message):
    is_chosen = await get_chosen_list(message.from_user.id)
    if not is_chosen:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Похоже, вы не выбрали ни одним из доступных TODO-листов. Сделайте это и повторите попытку( /chooselist)')
        return
    elif message.text == '/addtask':
        if not await taskcount_is_valid(message.from_user.id):
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Похоже, количество заданий в списке "{is_chosen}"\
     достигло максимума (50). Удалите часть заданий и повторите попытку')
            return
        await AddTaskFSM.addtask.set()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите текст задания:')
    elif message.text == '/deletetask':
        await GeneralFSM.deletetask.set()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите номер задания, которое хотите удалить:')
    elif message.text == '/marktask':
        await GeneralFSM.marktask.set()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                               'Введите номер задания, которое вы хотите пометить как выполненное:')
    elif message.text == '/edittask':
        await EditTaskFSM.edittask_num.set()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите номер задания, которое хотите отредактировать:')
    else:
        return


def register_fsm_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cancel_handler, state='*', commands=['cancel'])
    dp.register_message_handler(invoke_fsm, commands=['addtask', 'marktask', 'mark_all_tasks',
                                                      'edittask', 'deletetask', 'delete_completed_tasks',
                                                      'showlist', 'delete_completed_tasks', 'clearlist'], state=None)
    dp.register_message_handler(invoke_lm_fsm, commands=['createlist', 'deletelist', 'chooselist'], state=None)
```

Телеграм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, приведите код в виде текста. Во-вторых, больше кода. Что у вас возвращает `"Неизвестная команда`"? Есть ли хендлеры до этого? Какой стейт при вводе команды `/mark_all_tasks`? Зачем использовать такой отвратительный способ регистрации хендлеров? Есть ли какая-то ошибка в IDE?

Comment: 1. По поводу регистрации хендлеров: делал по python hub studio, он разбивал код на модули и вместо декораторов сделал функцию регистрации. 2. Стейта нет, он не требуется. При срабатывании команды производится одно действие, не требующее запуска фсм. 3. Неизвестная команда отловилась хендлером, который забирает всё, кроме зарезервированных команд. 4. ИДЕ молчит, там всё ок

Comment: Я тоже начинал с python hub studio, но пришёл к выводу что это ужас. Рекомендую вернутся к обычным декораторам [вот пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fob8oQOjB2Q&list=PLwVBSkoL97Q3phZRyInbM4lShvS1cBl-U&index=6).

Comment: А если поставить принт в начале mark_all_tasks? Что-то выдаст?

Comment: Нет, ничего. Я так понимаю, что крупно ошибся. Если команду ловит один хендлер, то другие этого делать дальше не будут, я прав? Если так, то вопрос снимается

Comment: Ну как бы так оно и есть